# Loading an edit form in a jquery modalbox cakephp 2.x

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0, modal-dialog

i've been following the blog tutorial in the cookbook and everything has worked ok, but now i need to display my edit form (posts/edit.ctp) inside a modalbox kinda like they do here

http://www.webbedit.co.uk/people/demo

and submit it using ajax, ive got a working ajax submit form working already in another cakephp installation, but i need to have it working inside a modalbox now

the problem is that i dont have much knowledge of jquery or ajax, i've looking for a solution or tutorial and only found some that work with CakePHP 1.3 or lower versions, i need a cakephp 2.x tutorial please, is there anyone that can help please?

Comment: nevermind i already have it working

Comment: how did you do it? any example?

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery for your ajax and use submit event change it to:

from:

```
$('#yourFormID').submit(function(){

});
```

to:

```
$('body').on('submit','#yourFormID',function(){
   //add your ajax code
});
```

and if use 'click' event exchange 'submit' with click

if handle your ajax with other way please add an example to your question